# Using css in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code. The first `if` condition is working, but the second `if` is not. I don't know why? The same CSS should be applied in the second `if` also. Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (location.pathname.indexOf("girl-clothing") != -1) {
        $(".RetailPriceValue").css("cssText", "margin: -203px 0 0 0 !important;");
    }

    if (location.pathname.indexOf("http://www.xyz.com/girl-clothing/?sort=featured&page=2")!= -1) {
        $(".RetailPriceValue").css("cssText", "margin:-220px 0 0 0 !important;");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is that 'cssText' property name?

Comment: escape sequence of the indexOf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that the first style change is working by coincidence. What you're actually adding is this:

```
<div style="cssText: margin: -203px 0 0 0 !important;"></div>
```

The problems here are obvious. Try this instead:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("girl-clothing") != -1) {
    $(".RetailPriceValue").css("margin", "-203px 0 0 0 !important;");
}

if (location.pathname.indexOf("http://www.xyz.com/girl-clothing/?sort=featured&page=2")!= -1) {
    $(".RetailPriceValue").css("margin", "-220px 0 0 0 !important;");
}
```

Comment: No its not working second css is not applying there.it is taking first css only.why?

Comment: Try removing the `!important` flags. Does the condition definitely hit? If you put an `alert()` in the second `if` statement does it appear?

Comment: In that case the problem is with your second `if` statement not matching the url - nothing to do with the `.css()`

Comment: then how to use that url?i want to apply it in that page?

Comment: You may want to double check the URL matches then. It's probably best to ask a different question about that though.

Answer (score 1):

use something like

```
$(".RetailPriceValue").css( "margin","-220px 0 0 0 !important");
```

so try instead

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("girl-clothing") != -1) {
    $(".RetailPriceValue").css("margin","-203px 0 0 0 !important");
}

if (location.pathname.indexOf("http://www.xyz.com/girl-clothing/?sort=featured&page=2")!= -1) {
    $(".RetailPriceValue").css( "margin","-220px 0 0 0 !important");
}
```

Comment: I have removed it,but still second css is not applying.atleast can you tell me how to remove  "margin: -203px 0 0 0 !important" at this "http://www.xyz.com/girl-clothing/?sort=featured&page=2" url???

Comment: what do you mean by stray??I think becoz of girl clothing it is taking previous css.isnt it?

Comment: @user1326201 is my anser helping or solving your problem ...?

Answer (score 1):

if your location.href is http://www.xyz.com/girl-clothing/?sort=featured&page=2

the location.pathname will be "/girl-clothing/", so indexOf function never will find the string "http://"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location